# Cannot install MvvmCross package in Class Library (Portable) - PCL

Tags: c#, nuget, mvvmcross, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

**System**: Windows 10 Education

**IDE**: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

**Description**:
Trying to make project from MvvmCross course(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGup08cz7LM&list=PLR6WI6W1JdeYSXLbm58jwAKYT7RQR31-W&index=2) exactly with same steps.

When I create new **Class Library (Portable)** project I want to add **MvvmCross** '*Getting Started*' package, but all I recieve after few seconds of instalation is that error:

```
Install-Package : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\{User Name}\.nuget\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack\3.5.1\content\portable-win%2Bnet45%2Bwp8%2Bwin8%2Bwpa81\ViewModels\FirstViewModel.cs.pp'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package mvvmcross
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I have tried run VS as administrator, restart system, install NuGet via Command, install NuGet via graphic interface and repeat all, but result was exactly the same
What can I do with that?
Please help :(

Comment: Looks like a [bug](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1087) in NuGet 3 in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @MattWard that was very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: [here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.PackageManagement/pull/51) is pull-request with fixed issue :)

Comment: @Borys, could you please add the solution you found as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any answer on that issue. 
**I uninstalled Enterprise Visual Studio and installed Community 2015.**

However after updates that Microsoft released on visual studio (and after few MvX's updates I think) the problem was gone, but I can't ensure if problem disappeared on Enterprise version.

Currently I have: 
*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015* 
*Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1*

Here are simple steps of creating new PCL project with success result of current problem:

**Step 1:** (Choosing template) 
[image: Choosing PCL template]

**Step 2:** (Setting APIs) 
[image: Setting up portable APIs]

**Step 3A:** (Installing MvX Package - Stable 3.5.1 version) 
[image: Searching for MvX version on NuGet]
*Result A:*

[image: Result message]

[image: Solution tree]

**Step 3B:** (Installing MvX Package - Prerelease 4.0.0-beta8 version) 
[image: Searching for MvX version on NuGet]
*Result B:*

[image: Result message]

[image: Solution tree]

Let me know here if Enterprise version problem is solved 
and sorry for image-step spam.